# Generic method and invalid context exception

Tags: c#, .net, generics, enums

I'm trying to code a custom authorization service where I register a module to check permissions for an specific enum representing available activities:

```
public interface IAuthorizationService
{
    void Register<T>(IAuthorizationModule module);
    bool Authorize<T>(T activity);
}

public class AuthorizationService : IAuthorizationService
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, IAuthorizationModule> activities;

    public AuthorizationService()
    {
        activities = new Dictionary<Type, IAuthorizationModule>();
    }

    public void Register<T>(IAuthorizationModule module)
    {
        activities[typeof(T)] = module;
    }

    public bool Authorize<T>(T activity)
    {
        return activities[typeof(T)].Authorize(activity);
    }
}
public interface IAuthorizationModule
{
    bool Authorize<T>(T activity);
}

public class OrderAuthModule : IAuthorizationModule
{
    public bool Authorize<OrderActivity>(OrderActivity activity)
    {
        return activity == OrderActivity.Cancel;
    }
}

public enum OrderActivity
{
    Place,
    Cancel,
    Refund
}
```

This code is failing to compile with the following exception:

`'OrderActivity' is a 'type parameter', which is not valid in the given context`

on line: `return activity == OrderActivity.Cancel;`.

I can't declare the interface as `IAuthorizationModule<T>` because I need a dictionary of `<Type, IAuthorizationModule>` to register the modules which will respond to the type `T` (enum).

What I'm missing here?

Comment: Which line is giving you the error ?

Comment: Ops, sorry. Edited with the line error.

Comment: can you put a constraint in your interface method luiz? of orderactivity

Comment: @terrybozzio I can't make the interface `IAuthorizationModule<T>`. Doing that makes impossible to create a `Dictionary<Type, IAuthorizationModule` to register the module which is responsible for type T (enum).

Comment: @terrybozzio Could you give me an example? I think I'm not following you...

Comment: sorry my mistake,just now i realized OrderActivity was enum,please tell me,the method is only for taking the enums values?if so i think i got the answer...i will post my answer based in that the method is only for taking OrderActivity values

Comment: Yes, `IAuthorizationModule.Authorize<T>` will only receive enums values.

Comment: answer posted luiz just changed 2 things where the coments are

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your design does not sound to me. From your concrete class and implementation of `AuthorizeService`, I assume that each `IAuthorizationModule` should responsible for only one type of activity. If I am right, so the interface should be declared as

```
public interface IAuthorizationModule<T>
{
    bool Authorize(T activity);
}

public class OrderAuthModule : IAuthorizationModule<OrderActivity>
{
    public bool Authorize<OrderActivity>(OrderActivity activity)
    {
        return activity == OrderActivity.Cancel;
    }
}
```

You also need to modify `AuthorizationService` accordingly:

```
public class AuthorizationService : IAuthorizationService
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, object> activities;

    public AuthorizationService()
    {
        activities = new Dictionary<Type, object>();
    }

    public void Register<T>(IAuthorizationModule<T> module)
    {
        activities[typeof(T)] = module;
    }

    public bool Authorize<T>(T activity)
    {
        return ((IAuthorizationModule<T>)activities[typeof(T)]).Authorize(activity);
    }
}
```

This way it's easier to implement each `IAuthorizationModule`.

Comment: You're right, each `IAuthorizationModule` is responsible for only one activity (enum). I liked your solution where I have to do type casting in just one place (`AuthorizationService`) instead of each `IAuthorizationModule`. Just one correction: method signature in `IAuthorizationModule<T>` should be `bool Authorize(T activity)`. Using `Authorize<T>` gives me the same error I was having... Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Updating `Authorize` to `<T>` could fix it..

```
public class OrderAuthModule : IAuthorizationModule
{
    public bool Authorize<T>(T activity)
    {
        return activity.ToString() == OrderActivity.Cancel.ToString();
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
        var authorization = new AuthorizationService();

        var orderMod = new OrderAuthModule();

        authorization.Register<OrderActivity>(orderMod);

        var status = authorization.Authorize(OrderActivity.Place);
```

Hope, I didn't get the context wrong...

**For the records:**

You can constrain a generic type parameter to be a value type (such as an int, a bool, and enum) or any custom structure using the struct constraint: [Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

```
public class MyClass<T> where T : struct 

{...}
```

Comment: Your answer is correct, but I chose @tia's answer as accepted because type casting occurs in just one place (`AuthorizationService`), instead of each `IAuthorizationModule`. Thank you very much for your help. :)

Answer (score 1):

Please try this out luiz

EDIT:

```
public bool Authorize<T>(T activity)
        {
            return activity.Equals(OrderActivity.Cancel);
        }
```

EDIT:
 to do switch statement try this out luiz

```
OrderActivity act = (OrderActivity)Enum.Parse(typeof(OrderActivity), activity.ToString());
            switch (act)
            {
                case OrderActivity.Place:
                    return true;
                    break;
                case OrderActivity.Cancel:
                    return false;
                    break;
                default:
                    return default(bool);
            }
```

The important is the line above switch(),there you parse the activity variable into the enum variable and place it into the switch,hope it helps......1)we where checking for equality on T(placeholder not set to anything in my case) and an enum value,in your case was the exception(using the type(T)) 2)it didnt work because we where dealing with T which is not define as anything specific,and swtch operates on bool,string,char,int,enum or corresponding nullable type and activity in my edit was T,glad i could help:)

Comment: I replied to your [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17099035/generic-method-and-invalid-context-exception/17099397?noredirect=1#comment24736483_17099035) stating that I would use just enum values before you edited it. Actually I will have more modules and enums (eg. `CustomerAuthModule` and `CustomerActivity`), hence the need for a generic solution. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: then this authorize method will be utilized in this class(OrderAuthModule) receiving various enums, or , will be implemented 1 method(Authorize) in diferent classes?...like,this class gets this method receiving orderactivity,other class gets this method but receiving other enum?

Comment: just edited luiz,tested it and got the right answers,hope to you will be the same...

Comment: Now it's working. :) Although your answer is correct, before marking it as accepted I have a couple questions: 1) Why can't I use a simple comparison (`==`) as I would in a normal situation? 2) I still can't use it in a switch statement, why? Nevertheless, thank you. :)

Comment: Your answer is correct, but I chose @tia's answer as accepted because type casting occurs in just one place (`AuthorizationService`), instead of each `IAuthorizationModule`. Thank you very much for your help. :)